# I am not able to install teamviewer 10 on kUbuntu

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, teamviewer

I Have tried to install Teamviewer 10 on kubuntu. It's showing me below error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install teamviewer_linux.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package teamviewer_linux.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'teamviewer_linux.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'teamviewer_linux.deb'
```

Comment: Under what path is the package?

Comment: `apt` is for repositories only. Use `dpkg` for installing `deb`-packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the .deb file then you have to run

```
dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

Explanation:

The `apt install` command is search and install from the repository.

You download package .deb format so you have to install it.

Comment: ach, ninjaed me...

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Debian 9 (and derivatives, with preliminary support in [apt 1.1~exp2](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/commit/fdff5b03e981ace063269640001b3bc8f9a42f4c)), `apt-get` can be used to install a local (*.deb* file) debian package . For it to distinguish this is a local package file, there has to be a `/` in the filename's path somewhere, since this character is invalid for the package name itself. So this should work instead:

```
apt-get install ./teamviewer_linux.deb
```

The advantage is since it's run through *apt*, missing dependencies will be installed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package you downloaded from the teamviewer-website with `dpkg`, not `apt-get`:

```
dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

and eventually follow up with

```
apt --fix-missing install
```